# How to write a SELECT DISTINCT query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have a list of categories, I'm able to use the select distinct statement but struggling to 'count' how many times a category was used, I have a column called Description and I need to create another column called occurrence.

```
Description
-------------
Arts, crafts, and collectibles
Baby
Beauty and fragrances
Books and magazines
Business to business
Clothing, accessories, and shoes
Computers, accessories, and services
Education
Electronics and telecom
Entertainment and media
Financial services and products
Food retail and service
Gifts and flowers
Government
Health and personal care
Home and garden
Nonprofit
Pets and animals
Religion and spirituality (for profit)
Retail (not elsewhere classified)
Services - other
Sports and outdoors
Toys and hobbies
Travel
Vehicle sales
Vehicle service and accessories
Books and magazines
Business to business
Clothing, accessories, and shoes
Computers, accessories, and services
Education
Electronics and telecom
Entertainment and media
Financial services and products
Food retail and service
Gifts and flowers
Government
Health and personal care
Services - other
Sports and outdoors
Toys and hobbies
Travel
Vehicle sales
Vehicle service and accessories
Books and magazines
Business to business
Clothing, accessories, and shoes
Business to business
Clothing, accessories, and shoes
Computers, accessories, and services
Education
Electronics and telecom
Entertainment and media
Financial services and products
Food retail and service
```

Comment: Read this please https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You can use a combination of `count(1)` and `group by`

Comment: Show us your query and explain exactly why the output is not what you wanted and why exactly you thought your query would produce it.

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a simple aggregation.

```
Select
   [Description]
   ,Occurences = Count([Description])
From
   YourTable
Group By
   [Description]
```

Comment: Well, it would do just what you asked. Perhaps what you asked isn't what you need. Why doesn't it work?

Comment: This is cool, I didn't know you could do 'alias = COUNT(column)'. Is there a difference doing equals as oppose to COUNT(column) as alias?

Comment: There is not @Simon but some people have [made good arguments](https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/23/bad-habits-to-kick-using-as-instead-of-for-column-aliases) why you shouldn't use `AS`

Comment: Just for the record, you can also do something like `Count(Description) Ocurrences` without the `as` keyword

Comment: It worked! Apologies for not taking a closer look at your answer, I'm grateful!

Comment: No problem @AfricanHeart